# "We can do this infinitely." Is this correct?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adverbs

I was told that it's not correct to say "We can do this infinitely", meaning that the process will last forever, without an end. Instead one should say "We can do this in*de*finitely" or "infinitely long". Is this right? why?

"Infinitely" and "indefinitely" look like complete synonyms for me in this context.

Comment: You cannot do anything infinitely, because you will die (or, if you don't believe that, your interlocutor will die, or the Sun will burn out, or the last proton will decay..). You *can* do something indefinitely, that is without a clearly identified point, specified in advance, when you will stop. The stopping point *exists* (as it must, because at the very least, you are going to die), but it is not *well-defined*.

Comment: I also think that "We can do this indefinitely" sounds right because indefinitely usually applies to time, whereas "We can do this infinitely" sounds wrong because infinitely usually applies to size.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Dan Bron wrote in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339669/we-can-do-this-infinitely-is-this-correct#comment781971_339669):

> You cannot do anything infinitely, because you will die (or, if you don't believe that, your interlocutor will die, or the Sun will burn out, or the last proton will decay..).
>
> You *can* do something indefinitely, that is without a clearly identified point, specified in advance, when you will stop. The stopping point *exists* (as it must, because at the very least, you are going to die), but it is not *well-defined*.

Comment: If the line at the movie theater is infinitely long can't we be standing in it infinitely? @DanBron  IOW, whatever happened to hyperbole? Thus, -1

Comment: @Clare Please comment under the question (where he actually commented) if you really want your message to reach Dan Bron. This is not visible to him.

Comment: I thought you could ping or signal (a user) in any comment. I think pinging in an actual question or answer post doesn't work. Maybe we can just wait and see. It's not of infinite importance that he be pinged, more so is the reason for my DV, even though I didn't have to give a reason, per meta.

Comment: @Clare I'm saying: this answer is technically mine, so only I get notified (unless there are other comments under this answer and you specifically tagged those commenters in your comment). There is no 'maybe' or 'wait and see'. I know what I'm talking about. :)